# No module named request PythonAnywhere error

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, pythonanywhere, pyvirtualdisplay

I need to use ***urllib*** module in my code and I import it like this:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
```

but PythonAnywhere returns the following error:

***> No module named request***

It looks like the ***urllib*** library is imported successfully when I try:

> python3 myscript.py

instead of:

> python myscript.py

But in this case I get another error:

***> No module named 'pyvirtualdisplay'***

***Pyvirtualdisplay*** is also needed in my code, so I dont know what to do. Can someone help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The urllib2 module has been split across several modules in Python 3 named urllib.request and urllib.error
>   ~ [urllib2 - python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)

When you run your script using

> python myscript.py

Your system is using python2 which doesn't have the `urllib.request` and `urllib.error` modules. Use the `urllib2` library.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Python extensions into each copy of Python that you use.  For example, `python` and `python3` use different set of extensions. You may have a script called `pip3` that installs extensions into your copy of Python 3.

Installation instructions on the [PyVirtualDisplay project page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay) state that first you'll need to install pip and [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) for Python 3. If you were using a Debian or Ubuntu VPS, these might work in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-imaging
sudo pip3 install pyvirtualdisplay
```

But a Google search tells me PythonAnywhere is a web application hosting service. The [list of supported extensions](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/batteries_included/) includes pyvirtualdisplay in Python 2 but not in Python 3. Just a guess, but the administrators may not be aware that pyvirtualdisplay has been ported. I'd recommend contacting PythonAnywhere support and requesting the extension's installation into Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can install pyvirtualdisplay yourself for python 3. Either use a virtualenv (there are details on the help pages) or use the `--user` argument to pip and ensure you use the correct version of pip (`pip3.3` or `pip3.4` depending on the version you want to use)